# Closing md-sidenav when router link is selected

Tags: angular2-routing, angular-material2

I am working on an angular project, I've implemented angular material components like the side-nav. The side-nav has ul li elements, where the links are nested and are router links not href. my question when I select a link to go to another view, I want to make a call to side nav to toggle and close. cause it always remains open

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:**

You can subscribe to `Router` events and close sidenav whenever router event takes place.

Code:

requires these imports:

```
import { Component,ViewChild, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MdSidenav, MdSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
```

in component class:

```
@ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav: MdSidenav;

  title = 'Tour of Heroes';

  constructor(private appService: AppService, 
              private _router: Router){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(() => {
      this.sidenav.close();
    });
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/j3wlDuvRa2c7zQuxPUGm?p=preview)

**Option 2:**

Add a `click` event to each `li` to close sidenav on click.

html:

```
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li class="sidenav__list">
    <a class="sidenav__list__link " (click)="sidenav.close()" >about</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[demo 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/wYaLD8Zho7zvtmCme7ms?p=preview)

Comment: Option 1 is a great solution.  Thank you!