# side-nav is closing for all devices on selecting router link

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using `side-nav` in my project, On resizing to mobile size toggle menu i,e `side-nav` will displayed on left likes this:

[image]

Now the issues the `side-nav` is closing on clicking `router link`
(ex customer) for for `all devices`, I want it to be closed only for small devices `(i,e mobile)`:

I know this is the duplicate of this [question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615414/closing-md-sidenav-when-router-link-is-selected)

But these answers makes the `side-nav` to close for all the devices.

**app-nav.html**

```
 <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
       <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav mat-elevation-z4" 
           fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 
           'dialog' : 'navigation'"
          [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="! 
          (isHandset$ | async)">

             <mat-toolbar>Business</mat-toolbar>
                    <h2>{{business.name}}</h2>
                    <p class="">{{business.branch}}</p>
             <mat-divider></mat-divider>

           <mat-nav-list>
             <mat-list-item>
             <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
             <a matLine>Home</a>
          </mat-list-item>

          <mat-list-item  [routerLink]="['../customer']">
           <mat-icon matListIcon>person</mat-icon>
           <a matLine>Customers</a>
          </mat-list-item>

          <mat-list-item>
           <mat-icon matListIcon>group</mat-icon>
           <a matLine>Staff</a>
         </mat-list-item>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <mat-sidenav-content>
         <mat-toolbar class="ylet-header"color="primary">
            <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button 
               (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
              <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
      </mat-sidenav-content>

 </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app-nav.ts**

```
   import { 
         BreakpointObserver,
         Breakpoints,
         BreakpointState,} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
  import { MatSidenav, TooltipPosition } from '@angular/material';
  import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  export interface IBusinessInfo {
        name: string;
        branch: string;
     }


  @Component({
   selector: 'ylb-app-nav',
   templateUrl: './app-nav.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app-nav.component.scss'],
  })
 export class AppNavComponent {

     public isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(map((result: BreakpointState) => result.matches));

     public business: IBusinessInfo = {
            name: 'Phone store',
            branch: 'India',
       };

       constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
                         private _router: Router) {}

       ngOnInit(): void {
             this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
             this.sidenavService.close();
           });

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you have to use one of the [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) events.

Just react to the `activate` or `deactivate` events to toggle the sidenav via `opened` input:

```
<router-outlet
  (activate)='onActivate($event)'
  (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
```

Use `BreakpointObserver` from [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) to retrieve the info "mobile or not?" like this:

```
this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(max-width: 767px)');
```

Comment: I want ot close the `side-nav` only for mobile.

Comment: @Empty_Soul you have to implement some logic based on the "is mobile?" information. What did you try and what didn't work?